# HTML element background horizontal scroll bug

Tags: html, css

This is my css:

```
.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    margin: 45px 10px 0px 10px;
}
#logData {
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #000;
}
.logMess {
    color:#000;
    padding: 4px 5px 2px 3px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.logMessBg {
    color:#000;
    padding: 4px 5px 2px 3px;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
```

And this is HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="logData">
        <p class="logMessBg">some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</p>
        <p class="logMess">some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the problem is with horizontal scroll. Because backgroud ends when `<p class="logMessBg">` text ends, but I want it to end when the longest `<p>` text ends. So, I want to background width all width.

Here is the screen:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the `.content` or `#logData` like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jdod6drn/)**

```
.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    margin: 45px 10px 0px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```